# How to make the strings of a guitar connect with the pegs?

Tags: mesh

I need to make the strings of my guitar and I have a problem with the part where the strings connect with the pegs. I need to make the string go around the pegs. Should I make them step by step the classic way without modifiers or is there an easier way?

[image: guitar image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you could use curves with a curve modifier and an Array modifier

Add Your curve: 
[image]

Adapt your curve:
[image]

Add a new cylinder and assing it a curve modifier and an array modfier:
[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and cleaner to just add a bevel object or directly bevel the curve?

Comment: @bstnhnsl Thats another way too! i think its a matter of choice, with the cylinder you have a little bit more control over the mesh